# Clarification required for "Windows Error Reports discontinuing support" announcement

Tags: windows-error-reporting

When I logged on to The WinQual site this morning the update message below was displayed. I'm slightly confused by the wording of the last paragraph. Does this mean that "support" will no longer be available for WER for XP. Or that there will no longer be xp/errors reports logged and process?

> **Attention Required**: Scheduled Winqual Site Downtime Starting February 9, 2012 during which all Winqual services will be unavailable. 
>   On February 9, 2012 at 6:00 P.M. Pacific Standard Time, Winqual will go offline and service will return on or before February 16, 2012 at 12:00 P.M. Pacific Standard Time. During this period, the Winqual site will be unavailable. We ask you to plan ahead for this interruption of Winqual service. There will be no method available during this time to view or perform Logo submissions, Device Metadata submissions, obtain VeriSign certificates, sign legal agreements or use any other services currently provided through the Winqual site.
>
> This is scheduled maintenance and mail will be sent to all Winqual
>   members when service returns.
>
> **Attention Required**: Windows Error Reports discontinuing support for Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 error reports  Based on the
>   mainstream support lifecycle of Windows, we are discontinuing support
>   of Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 Windows Error Reporting (WER)
>   data. Support will end on February 9, 2012.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a programming component to this question. I am sure there's a more suitable StackExchange site for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by that statement as well and sent an e-mail to winqual support asking if it meant WER will no longer collect crash reports for Windows XP?  which I found hard to believe since it still fairly widely used OS.  the response I got was not quite clear either...

**This change is based on mainstream support lifecycle of Windows.

In general though for generic bugs on Win 7 you should get coverage across multiple OS. Overall we are seeing a very low percentage of the data flow through based Windows XP. Also Windows XP data can only classify issues as an Event/Bucket level (see this blog for more information on Buckets versus server side analysis), which can provide a misleading analysis of the faulting issue.**

so I was just waiting for the WinQual site to come back online and see what's available.

(FYI, I visited the site for the first time today and none of my programs and crash reports were available and I added that as a separate question here on StackOverflow)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  "not quite clear" is true! At least you go a reply, I've tried a few of the address listed on the old site, some bounced, none replied :(